# Right method to use for tiles of buildings in various phases of construction

Tags: modeling, objects, workflow

We are working on a game with isometric tiles. We have decided to use blender to create models for objects we need (mostly buildings) and render to image to get our tiles.

Now we need different tiles showing progress of a building being built, say at 20% of construction progress, then 40, 60, 80 and 100%.

We initially used different layers to add the new brick layers added between two stages. The problem with this approach is that we do not get a single object and it is a collection of objects scattered on different layers which are tricky to correctly position.

Another method we thought of was saving the model at various stages of construction progress. This method also has the disadvantage of having multiple files for a single object.

Update:
Yet another method we just briefly checked is using *shape keys*. That too, seems to serve a different objective. So the main question still is:

Is there a better method to use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know which game engine you are using. But probably you could use 'shape keys'. At least in the bge that would work fine and it would be easy to set up.

you crate different shape keys.

Than you create an animation with all the shape keys.

You can use logic Bricks to create a logic which controlls the animation with a property.

Than you just have to change the property and your building gets upgraded.
It also would be easy to crate a little blending animation so that the new stage doesn't just pop up.

Probably I didn't describe that too good so I added a .blend to [Download](https://www.dropbox.com/s/fbna6vnkec6s99w/Building.blend?dl=0) where you can see what i mean. Just start the bge with <kbd>p</kbd> and use <kbd>w</kbd> and  <kbd>s</kbd> to transform the building.

I see that this method doesnt serve the job very well for a 2D java game.
Another method would be to use the 'restrict Rendering' Button in the Outliner.

The workflow would be:

Create the Building...

[image]

Than you mark everything which should be visible in the first stage. Go to frame 1 in the 'TimeLine' an Press <kbd>i</kbd> over the Camara Icon of ALL the Objects of the building.

[image]

Next you do the same for frame two...

[image]

The nice thing with this Method is that you now just can render an animation from Frame 1 to the Frame with the final stage (for example 5). If you configure your render output as in the picture below than you will get seperate Images of all Stages.

[image]

than you will get separate pictures of all stages.
I just pressed the animation button and had all the images int the right folder and with good names.

[image]

you also can configure the names by just writing the name behing the path.

[image]

Hopefully this is a good method for your project.

Comment: Thank you for the time and effort! We are not using blender itself to make the game. The game is browser based and uses javascript and canvas 2d. So all we need is a set of 5 still images per building. In the game no animation would be shown. Instead if a building takes 5 weeks to be constructed and a week in game-time translates to 10 minutes in real-world time, then we would show the 0% image initially and every 10 minutes swap it with the appropriate image to show construction progress. Blender in this context is used to deliver those still images. But we need to keep our files manageable.

Comment: oh sorry ! i didn't understand your Question correctly my fault.

Comment: :) Anyway, using shape keys is a possibility, but I would like to know about other alternatives if there are any. To a newbie like me, blender is like a huge labyrinth - the fact that I know how to get to point x does not mean I know the best path to x.

Comment: yes Bledner is Huge. I added another and probably a better answer.

Comment: Thank you again. In this method, the building has to consist of separate parts right? Or is it somehow possible to change the mesh of part 1 to be part 2 (with subdividing/extruding)?

Comment: Yes it's the easiest way to keep them in seperate objects. But that souldn't be a problem. You can model your object as one piece and than select all the parts which should appear in other 'Stages' and press P-> choose selected

Answer (score 0):

You are using the Blender game engine to achieve what should be far easier to achieve by simply animating the visibility and or renderability of objects.

And since this has been answered (with multiple good answers) on Stack Overflow before I'm just going to link to the other question/thread:

[How to make an object invisible at a particular key-frame without moving it in Blender (2.59)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8844389/how-to-make-an-object-invisible-at-a-perticular-keyframe-without-moving-it-in-bl)

Comment: Maybe I should have pointed in my question that [I am not using blender game engine at all](http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/33610/right-method-to-use-for-tiles-of-buildings-in-various-phases-of-construction/33623#comment53350_33619).

Comment: Yes, very much a mistake on my end.

I managed to some-how look at Togers answer and think it to be your question, then I downloaded the blend file in he's post - looked at it and was wondering why he(in my mind at that point - you) would use the game engine to achieve what would be better done trough keyframe animation.


Still, I would suggest for you to look at the link I had posted.
I suspect it offers a good solution for your problem.